# Woocommerce Applying Coupon on Specific product in Cart

Tags: woocommerce

I want to apply the discount coupon to the specific product in cart from checkout page.

Inside the cart:

product1 w/ upgrades

product2 w/o upgrades

when I apply the discount coupon I want that the discount will take effect only in product2's price. I tried to search in some forums but the coupon will take effect in the whole cart items.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code:

```
function calculate_variation_addon_price( $cart_object ) {
    global $isProcessed;
    // Loop for all products in cart
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        // Your condition here for product specific i.e. id == 25
        if((!isset($isProcessed) || empty($isProcessed))) {

            $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->get_price() );

            $cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['data']->set_price( $orgPrice * 0.5 );
        }
    }
    $isProcessed = 1;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_variation_addon_price', 2, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding coupon from admin panel, find a tab there, called 'Usage Restriction'.

There you can add products or product categories or even exclude some for the coupon code to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can so that using product id, sku or name

```
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discounting_amount, $price_to_discount , $cart_item, $single, $coupon ) {    
    // On backorder
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_id() !== 'product2_id' ) {
        $discounting_amount = 0;
    }
    return $discounting_amount;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
```

You can use in_array instead of !== for multiple products
You also replace get_id() by other properties or use custom attributs...